# fetching latest login info of each user in List

Tags: apex, soql

I am trying to fetch the one latest login History of the each User using below SOQL query.

```
loginHstryList=[SELECT Id,UserId,LoginTime, Platform,Status,Browser from LoginHistory where UserId =: userIds order by LoginTime DESC];
```

But it is returning each and every login attempt of user which is obvious. I need to store one latest login attempts for each users in my list.I don't want the old login info of the same user. Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, unless you care only about `LoginTime`. You can get the most recent time of each user's login using the `MAX` aggregation. If you want other details specific to that record, you will need to use post-filter processing and an `ORDER BY` clause.

```
// if you only care about LoginTime
Map<Id, AggregateResult> results = new Map<Id, AggregateResult>([
    SELECT UserId Id, MAX(LoginTime) FROM LoginHistory GROUP BY UserId
]);

// if you care about other fields
Map<Id, LoginHistory> logins = new Map<Id, LoginHistory>();
for (LoginHistory login : [SELECT ... FROM LoginHistory WHERE ... ORDER BY LoginTime DESC])
{
    if (!logins.contains(login.UserId))
    {
        logins.put(login.UserId, login);
    }
}
```